# CSS Scale an element with 100% width

Tags: css, webkit-transform

I am interested in zooming out a div with 100% width. The problem I am having, is when I scale the element out it gets a fixed width and no longer extends 100% of the width.

Example - http://jsfiddle.net/Fz7qh/2/

When I use the CSS zoom property (as opposed to transform: scale) it works as expected, but I hear the zoom property is not well supported. My question is can this be achieved with CSS transform scale?

Comment: The CSS `zoom` property is indeed poorly supported. Neither Firefox nor Opera support it.

Comment: Is this what you're after? http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/Fz7qh/5/

Comment: @thirtydot interesting idea. Seems to work. Post it as an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 59, accepted):

To emulate what the `zoom` property does in this case, you can add `-transform-origin: 0 0;` and set the `width` to `oldWidth / newScale` (`100 / 0.7 ~= 142.857143`):

http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/Fz7qh/5/

```css
div.zoomed {
    -webkit-transform: scale(.7);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
    width: 142.857143%;
}​
```

Comment: I just added `box-sizing: border-box;` also just to make sure the `padding` is also included in `width`

Comment: In IE11 I get scrollbar after clicking on the image. Any ideas why?

Comment: Ok, I've found out: you need to add outer element and scale it depending on the zoom like here http://jsfiddle.net/v2fukeq5/11/ (+ overflows for non-const height).