# Stretch and scale font-awesome icon dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, css, font-awesome

I've seen countless snippets [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14736496/use-font-awesome-icons-in-css), to include a font as a "background image":

```
div 
{
    width : 100%;
    height : 200px;
    margin : 20px;
    background-color : grey;
    color : #fff;
    position : relative;
}

div:before
{
      position:absolute;
        font-family: FontAwesome;
        top:0;
        left:0px;
      font-size : 100px;
      content: "\f003";
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JfGVE/639/)

Result:

[image]

Is there a way to make the font resize dynamically to fill 100% size as a background image, similar to any of the methods used [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1150163/stretch-and-scale-a-css-image-in-the-background-with-css-only)? Or is there any way I can use it properly as a background image in a responsive page, where I wouldn't know the width/height of the container it's going to fill?

I'm thinking of using transforms: [Css, Can I stretch text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6351013/css-can-i-stretch-text)
But in my case it's difficult because I don't know how much I have to scale it.

I thought I'd ask this question because maybe there's a way to do it, prior to just falling back to a plain old background image.

Additional links that didn't help (much):

- [Font scaling based on width of container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16056591/font-scaling-based-on-width-of-container)
- [CSS Scale an element with 100% width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10937154/css-scale-an-element-with-100-width)
- [Have text scale up in size to fit the container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8990999/have-text-scale-up-in-size-to-fit-the-container)
- [resize font-size according to div size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13358181/resize-font-size-according-to-div-size)

Comment: So you want the icon to change its size depending on the size of the div?

Comment: I want the icon to fill the div. Like `background-size:cover;`

Comment: @David Its better to use `svg` if you're not sure of `height` `width` as *font-awesome* is not something which you can manage with `background-size: cover` its has to be manageable with `font-size` then instead of that you can go for `svg` viz best suited as you're looking for icons to fill whatever size you want as `background-image`.

Comment: Well, why don't you try calculate font-size with JavaScript. Alternatively, there's `vw` unit for font size, which adjust to viewport width.

Comment: Figured as much. I'm just going to use https://github.com/encharm/Font-Awesome-SVG-PNG

Comment: Here I have a similar question. It has no solution, but the scaling works in both directions for font. Not working for font-awesome but I have a feeling that this is just due to my misunderstanding something to do with DOM, or with font-awesome's default styling. Maybe we can work it out together :P.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47181524/vanilla-js-resize-font-awesome-to-fit-container